# Why is Node.JS only accepting one request at a time, leaving the port in TIME_WAIT even after socket closure?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, networking, fetch-api

So, I am trying to make a simple express app that can handle requests and send a response. When I send a request from a client, the express app receives it. The connection between the client and the server will stay for roughly 30 seconds, and if it doesn't receive any other input, it will close the socket. (This is my assumption). Then, it won't accept any other requests for the next ~2 minutes. It simply doesn't hear them. No errors or anything. The client will hang, timing out from not hearing from the server.

Suspicious that this was a network issue, I used 'netstat' and checked the status of port 3000. (The port I was running the express app on) During the starting window, the server will receive the connection from the and hold onto it, still receiving sequential requests during this window. (See below) The port's status reads ESTABLISHED in the command prompt.

```
C:\Users\Administrator>netstat -a -n -b | find "3000"
  TCP    0.0.0.0:3000           0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
  TCP    192.168.254.64:3000    192.168.254.254:3000   ESTABLISHED
  TCP    [::]:3000              [::]:0                 LISTENING
```

If the client goes quiet for more than 30 seconds, then it will enter into another state. It's usually either TIME_WAIT or FIN_WAIT_2. Regardless, both leave me with the same issue: I have to wait 2 minutes before the port opens again, and I can send another GET request from the client to the server.

```
C:\Users\Administrator>netstat -a -n -b | find "3000"
  TCP    0.0.0.0:3000           0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
  TCP    192.168.254.64:3000    192.168.254.254:3000   TIME_WAIT
  TCP    [::]:3000              [::]:0                 LISTENING
```

```
C:\Users\Administrator>netstat -a -n -b | find "3000"
  TCP    0.0.0.0:3000           0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
  TCP    192.168.254.64:3000    192.168.254.254:3000   FIN_WAIT_2
  TCP    [::]:3000              [::]:0                 LISTENING
```

**Desired solution:**

I want to have the port open and receive requests, and then if more than 30 seconds go by, the socket closes and goes back into the listening state immediately. I want to be able to hear from multiple clients simultaneously instead of just serving one request at a time. If you know a solution, please let me know. I am a beginner to all this, and I just want to find a way to get this to work. I appreciate your patience.

**Notes:**

- I noticed that when the destination IP for the connection reads 192.168.254.254. This is odd because even though the client and the server are on the same network, the server's IP is 192.168.254.64, and the client's IP is 192.168.254.134. The Wi-Fi router's address is 192.168.254.254, and you can access all its settings if you type that IP into the browser. This makes me think that this socket hanging issue might be a network/firewall problem(?):

```
  TCP    192.168.254.64:3000    192.168.254.254:3000   ESTABLISHED
```

(Client IP Configuration)

```
Wireless LAN adapter Wi-Fi:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : home
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fd70::73f8:aa30:6941:%20
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.254.134
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.254.254
```

- I tried this both with the Express.JS package, using the express app API, along with using Node.JS's built-in http.createServer API. Both APIs yielded the same issue.
- Could this perhaps be a windows issue? The client runs Windows 11, and the server runs Windows Server 2022

Client Code (JS):

```
var options = {
    method: "GET",
    mode: "no-cors",
    headers: {
        "credentials": "alfredo",
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*"
    }
};

async function sendRequest() {
    const response = await fetch('http://63.219.237.215:3000/', options);
    const data = await response;
    console.log(data);

}
```

Server Code: (NODE.JS using Express Package)

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const port = 3000;

app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log('Server has started.')
})

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    console.log("request recieved" + new Date().toISOString);
    res.send('Hello World!');
})
```

**Related Questions that didn't fix the problem (all found on Stack Overflow):**

Avoiding TIME_WAIT

Setting TIME_WAIT TCP

Node.js server not responding to GET request .ECONNRESET error when accessing localhost:8080

How to close (kill, release?) a socket, which is in FIN_WAIT_2 state?

Unable to make 2 parallel TCP requests to the same TCP Client

How to handle multiple concurrent requests with express?

Properly close a TCP socket

---

- My Public IP address shown in my client code was randomized for safety.